# Find and replace date formats in markdown text

Tags: date, replace, find, markdown

I'm not sure if this is possible and have tried unsuccessfully to find out online.

I have a journal in Ulysses (a markdown editor for Mac/iOS). I create a new sheet (markdown document) for each entry, and the first line is the date in this format:

```
24/2/2019, 09:49
```

I have nearly 500 entries in this way. I'm interested in moving my journal to Day One app, and in order to import in this way, I need to change the date format for every entry to:

```
Date:   June 24, 2016 at 10:59:06 AM MDT
```

Is there a way to do this somehow in an automated fashion? I don't think I could bear to go through around 500 entries and manually rewrite the date.

Comment: The sort answer is that you can write a script to do this. However, I don't expect anyone to provide a full script for you. What have you tried? Which language(s) do you have available on your system and/or are you comfortable using (bash, JavaScript, Python, Perl, ... to name a few)?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include a few actual lines from the markdown file. It might help to also explain a bit more about the file format being used. What language/app were you considering to use? e.g. Python?